# Warning: Supported orientations are not matched pairs (Info.plist)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, orientation, simulator

I get that error while compiling, not sure why but another problem which seems to be coming from it is that the orientation of the simulator is landscape (which is what I've intended) however the x/y positions of the screen cordinates still think they're in portrait, so the simulator shows up in landsacpe but graphics are drawn as if it were in portrait, this is what my info.plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably to late to be helpful (I found it by googling) but that *warning* (if it's the *error* you mentioned) is a simple check (to make sure you're not forgetting something).

IOW fixing the warning (not to show by adding `LandscapeRight` won't change the behaviour of your application. The real issue is somewhere else.